# How to Convert a Mesh's A-Pose to T-Pose

Tags: armature, pose-mode

I have a mesh that was delivered to me in A-pose, and I would like to be able to retarget mixamo and other animations over the course of the project. The problem is I can't figure out how to get the mesh to adopt the new pose structure.

Mixamo animations rest pose is a T-pose. I can skin the model by deleting the animation setting it into an A-pose. Applying the animation again without resetting the armature to an T-pose results in the arms being crossed (the result of adjusting the upper arm rotation). Trying to skin then reset the armatures rest pose to a T-pose results in the mesh not retaining its position on the armature...it reverts to an A-pose.

This SURELY must be something people come across all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could duplicate the *Armature* modifier, disable the copy:

[image]

Raise the arms in *Pose* mode so that it gives a T pose to the object:

[image]

Apply the active *Armature* modifier to make the object's T pose definitive:

[image]

Bring back your armature to its default T pose (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>), re-enable the remaining *Armature* modifier:

[image]

Comment: APPLY the armature! I would never have thought of that. I will try this tomorrow and get back to you here and if it works mark it as answered. Thank you very very much for this fantastic and thoughtful answer.

Comment: Just want to say thank you this worked. It's key to return the armature back to pose mode. The model will still require editing of the imported animation but the starting point is much less out of whack.

Comment: OK great, you're welcome  ;)